# Сохранение дубликатов строк

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe5

Как сохранить все дубликаты строк, **именно сохранить** а не удалить.

Вот так удаление идет дубликатов а вот интересно **как их сохранить** в отдельный файл ?

```
var
    f1: TextFile;
    st: string;
    s: TStringList;

  begin
    AssignFile(f1, '1.txt');
    reset(f1);
    s := TStringList.Create;
    While not EOF(f1) do
    begin
      readln(f1, st);
      If s.IndexOf(st) < 0 then
        s.Add(st);
    end;

    s.SaveToFile('2.txt');
    s.Free;
    CloseFile(f1);
  end;
```

**То есть были строки:**

```
123
123
4444
55555
123
```

**И на выходе база:**

```
123
123
123
```

**Дополнение: Можно сделать вот так:**

```
var
  f1: TextFile;
  st: string;
  s, s1: TStringList;
begin
  AssignFile(f1, '1.txt');
  reset(f1);
  s := TStringList.Create;
  s1 := TStringList.Create;
  while not EOF(f1) do
  begin
    readln(f1, st);
    if s.IndexOf(st) < 0 then
      s.Add(st)
    else
      s1.Add(st);
  end;
 
  s.SaveToFile('2.txt');
  s1.SaveToFile('double.txt');
  s.Free;
  s1.Free;
  CloseFile(f1);
end;
```

Но получается что в файле **double.txt** не все дубликаты сохраняются.

**То есть были строки:**

```
123
123
4444
55555
123
```

**В файле 2.txt результат**

```
123 - Вот тут запись а она должна быть в файле **double.txt**
4444
55555
```

В файле **double.txt** результат

```
123
123
```

То есть одна строка **123** не туда записалась. Как это можно исправить ?

Comment: А исходный порядок строк важен?

Comment: @Alekcvp, Порядок строк не важен. Буду благодарна за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну у меня навскидку как-то так получилось. Явно не самый оптимальный вариант.

```
var
  s: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  d: Boolean;
begin
  s := TStringList.Create;
  s.Duplicates := dupAccept;
  s.LoadFromFile('1.txt');
  s.Sort;
  i := 0;
  d := False;
  while i < s.Count - 1 do
  begin
    if s[i] = s[i + 1] then
    begin
      d := True;
      Inc(i);
    end else if not d then
      s.Delete(i)
    else begin
      d := False;
      Inc(i);
    end;
  end;
  if not d then
    s.Delete(i);
  s.SaveToFile('double.txt');
  s.Free;
end;
```

Comment: А еще такой вопрос а открытие файла через AssignFile как реализовать в вашем коде ? Потому как бывают файлы большие и не помещаются в память.

Comment: Никак, тут весь механизм построен на том что весь файл в памяти. Если файл в память не помещается, то алгоритм очень сильно усложнится. Т.к. для поиска уникальных строк требуется проверять только уже найденные строки, то для поиска дубликатов необходимо проверять весь файл.

Comment: Хорошо, благодарна Вам буду изучать код.

Comment: Мой алгоритм простой: мы сортируем строки, после этого все одинаковые строки идут друг за другом. После этого мы просто сравниваем каждую строку с предыдущей (`d = true`) и следующей (`s[i] = s[i + 1]`). Если совпадает хоть с одной, значит оставляем, если нет - удаляем.